# How to create multiple HTML elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is to create a table pager control using jQuery.
It contains lots of links and spans. I've managed to do this with plain string concatenation, but I can't believe that jQuery can't make this more elegant.
I can't use jTemplates here since the generation has quite a bit of procedural logic.

Question: is there a way to create an array of HTML elements with jQuery and append them to some container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$('First Element').add($('Second Element')).appendTo($('body'))`

Comment: This may have worked in 2009, but today it fails with an error message that depends on jQuery version. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtxg22oo/1/). What works is `$('first').add($('second')).appendTo(...)`.

Comment: I tested this and @romkyns is right. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

String concatenation (or Array.join) is fine, as long as you make it pretty ;)

```
var structure = [
    '<div id="something">',
        '<span>Hello!</span>',
    '</div>'
];

$(structure.join('')).appendTo(container);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is always [append()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append).

```
$('#container').append('<span>foobar baz</span>');
```

It seems to me that just using string concatenation and append would be the least complex, and probably fastest option. However, following is an *untested* example of a way to (arguably) simplify the creation of elements, and allow you to append them to a given parent element:

```
function elemCreate(type, content, attrs) {
   /* type: string tag name
    * content: string element content
    * attrs: associative array of attrs and values
    */
    elem = '<' + type + '></' + type + '>'
    e = $(elem).attr(attrs)
    e.append(content)
    return e
}

stuff = [];    
stuff.push(elemCreate('a', 'Click me!', {'href': 'http://stackoverflow.com'});

$(stuff).appendTo($('#container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simplify things by doing like this :)

```
$('.parentElement').append(`
   <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
`);
```

Just need to used `` or back quote inside the append method