# Building elements with nested content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, markup, createelement

I use the following to create objects in JavaScript using jQuery:

```
var article_attrs = { 
        'class' : 'class-name',
        click : function_name,
        hover : function_name,
        html : $('<h2>', { html : "Heading" })
    },
    article = $('<article>', atricle_attrs);
```

This works great - by setting the `html` attribute I set the content of the article.

What I want to do at this point though, is add a `<h2>` tag, and a `<div>` tag including a `<footer>` tag. My outline for this element will look like:

- article

  - h2
  - div

    - footer

What would be the best way of doing this? (Note this is an example only).

**Update: The main question is, using the `html` attribute, how do I add multiple elements?**

I have tried a method from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/747192/687581), but it does not work in this case:

```
html : [ $('<h2>', { html : "Heading" }), $('<div>', { html : "Some content" }) ]
```

I have made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLCTF/20/) which works.. but my JS still doesn't. I'm definitely missing something.

Edit: Works with jQuery 1.8.* only

Comment: `$("<element1>").add("<element2>")` might do the trick.

Comment: @Shikyo: `add()` adds another element to the jQuery selection, I think the question is 'how do I append am element to a newly-created jQuery object?'

Answer (score 0):

you could simply write like so

```
$('<h2></h2><div><footer></footer></div>').appendTo(article)
```

Comment: I could, yes. However I like having control over all the attributes using object notation and would really like to find a method along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myEle = $("<article />").append(
                 $("<h2 />").text("...")
             ).append(
                 $("<div />").append(
                     $("<footer />")
                 )
             );
```

You can nest jQuery `.append()` method calls like above to create the HTML structure you need. I like this method because it makes it easy to visualize what the HTMl structure will be when you read it.

The above code would render this HTML:

```
<article>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</article>
```